# List[String] does not have a member traverse from cats

Tags: scala, traversal, scala-cats, either

I am attempting to convert a `List[Either[Int]]` to an`Either[List[Int]]` using `traverse` from `cats`.

**Error**

```
[error] StringCalculator.scala:19:15: value traverseU is not a member of List[String]
[error]       numList.traverseU(x => {
```

**Code**

```
  import cats.Semigroup
  import cats.syntax.traverse._
  import cats.implicits._


  val numList = numbers.split(',').toList
  numList.traverseU(x => {
      try {
          Right(x.toInt)
      } catch {
        case e: NumberFormatException => Left(0)
      }
    })
      .fold(
        x => {},
        x => {}
      )
```

> I have tried the same with traverse instead of traverseU as well.

**Config(for cats)**

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    inThisBuild(List(
      organization := "com.example",
      scalaVersion := "2.12.4",
      scalacOptions += "-Ypartial-unification",
      version      := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
    )),
    name := "Hello",
    libraryDependencies += cats,
    libraryDependencies += scalaTest % Test
  )
```

Comment: See the [release notes](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/releases) the method was removed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should indeed be just `traverse`, as long as you're using a recent cats version (1.0.x), however, you can't import both `cats.syntax` and `cats.implicits._` as they will conflict.

Unfortunately whenever the Scala compiler sees a conflict for implicits, it will give you a really unhelpful message.

Remove the `cats.syntax` import and it should work fine.
For further information check out the [import guide.](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/imports.html)

Answer (score 3):

You need only `cats.implicits._`. e.g.

```
import cats.implicits._

val numbers = "1,2,3"
val numList = numbers.split(',').toList
val lst = numList.traverse(x => scala.util.Try(x.toInt).toEither.leftMap(_ => 0))

println(lst)
```